# Update name (different from previous) in a trigger SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I'm writing a trigger for a company database, and this trigger is intended to update a name of an employee (in the rare case of changing name for example) that should be different from a previous one, or NOT NULL.

This is the code I wrote. It compiles but it gives me error on the update (ORA-04091: table COMPANY.EMPLOYEE is mutating, trigger/function may not see
it). I've noticed that is caused by `FOR EACH ROW`, but I cannot remove that because otherwise the `:new` and `:old` references will not work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NO_INVALID_NAME
AFTER UPDATE OF EMPLOYEE_NAME ON EMPLYEE 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  INVALID_NAME EXCEPTION;
  CORRECT_NAME EXCEPTION;

BEGIN
  UPDATE EMPLOYEE 
  SET EMPLOYEE_NAME =:NEW.EMPLOYEE_NAME
  WHERE EMPLOYEE_NAME =:OLD.EMPLOYEE_NAME;

  IF :NEW.EMPLOYEE_NAME <> :OLD.EMPLOYEE_NAME AND IS NOT NULL THEN
    RAISE INVALID_NAME;
  ELSE
    RAISE CORRECT_NAME;
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN NOME_NON_CORRETTO
    THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20009,'Name cannot be updated.');
  WHEN CORRECT_NAME 
    THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Updated.');
END;
```

i guess i'm messing up something with the :NEW and :OLD statement, but i can't see where.

Comment: Have you checked this?   [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS2005)

Comment: i've consulted the docs a lot, but maybe you can suggest me some page that should do the trick for my code ?

Comment: I don't understand the business rule here. Why is an update trigger trying to update its own table? Why is `employee_name` allowed to be null? If you want to prevent changes to the name then just raise an exception `if :new.employee_name <> :old.employee_name`. If names are allowed to change, then what is the trigger for?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the table name in the 2nd line, so let's change it to  EMPLOYEE.

`AFTER UPDATE OF EMPLOYEE_NAME ON EMPLOYEE`

I would try to add :NEW.EMPLOYEE_NAME before IS NOT NULL clause, but I am sure if it fixes all the problems.

```
IF(:NEW.EMPLOYEE_NAME <> :OLD.EMPLOYEE_NAME AND :NEW.EMPLOYEE_NAME IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: yes, sorry for that, EMPLYEE was a mistake.
Also :NEW.EMPLOYEE_NAME IS NOT NULL is not working tho, still gave me the( ORA-04091: table COMPANY.EMPLOYEE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it ) error.

Comment: maybe it's just the order of the operation that's not working right ?

Comment: Putting the IF block before UPDATE would be a good idea. This way the invalid name would not be assigned to an employee. And instead of 'Name cannot be updated.' the exception could throw 'Invalid name. Did not update the employee'.

Answer (score 0):

In the trigger you do the same operation like in the update.
So - the "application" makes an update (without commit) then the trigger makes the same update and then it verifies the `:new.name` and the `old.name`.

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NO_INVALID_NAME
BEFORE UPDATE ON EMPLOYEE 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    INVALID_NAME EXCEPTION;
    CORRECT_NAME EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.EMPLOYEE_NAME <> :OLD.EMPLOYEE_NAME AND :NEW.EMPLOYEE_NAME IS NOT NULL THEN
        RAISE INVALID_NAME;
    ELSE
        RAISE CORRECT_NAME;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NOME_NON_CORRETTO
        THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20009,'Name cannot be updated.');
    WHEN CORRECT_NAME 
        THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Updated.');
END;
```